# Simple Perl string Problem

Tags: perl

I know this might be very easy to some,,

I have a simple string like this `@¨0­+639172523299` (with characters before a mobile number). My question is, how do i remove all the characters before the plus(+)? What i know is to remove a **known** character as follows:

`$number =~ tr/://d;` (if i want to remove a colon)

But here, I want all characters before '+' to be removed.

Comment: usual general comment about how it's 'Perl' and not 'PERL'. if you're learning from sources using the term 'PERL', then there's a chance that they are out-of-date or not advocating good, current programming practices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove everything up to and including the first +, you can do:

```
$number ~= s/.*\+//;
```

If you want to keep the +, you can put that into the replacement:

```
$number ~= s/.*\+/+/;
```

The above says: Match "anything" (the `.*`) followed by a `+` (`+` is a special character in regular expressions, which is why it needs the backslash escape) and replace it with nothing (or in the above example, replace it with a single `+`).

Note that the above will strip out everything up to the LAST `+` in the string, which may not be what you want. If you want to keep strip out everything up to the FIRST `+` in a string, you can do:

```
$number =~ s/[^+]*\+//;
```

or

```
$number =~ s/[^+]*\+/+/; # Keep the +
```

The difference from the first regular expression being the `[^+]*` instead of `.*`, which means "match any character except a `+`".

For more information on Perl's regular expressions, the perldoc [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) manual page is pretty good, as is O'Reilly's [Mastering Regular Expressions](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596002893) book.

Answer (score 2):

in the simplest case

```
$string =~ s/^.*\+//;
```

if you have more than one "+" before the mobile number

```
$string="@+0+0­+639172523299";
@s=split /\+/,$string;
print $s[-1];
```

In fact, you can just use `split()` instead of regex. Its easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
my $string = '@¨0­+639172523299';
$string =~ s/(.*)(?=\+)//;
print $string;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$number =~ s/^.*\+//;
```

Answer (score 0):

`s/(.*?\+)(.*)/\2/;`

> If you  want plus to be remain

s/(.*?)(\+)(.*)/\2\3/;

Answer (score 0):

```
my $str="@¨0­+639172523299";
if($str=~/(\D+)(\+[0-9]+)/)
{
  print $2;
}
```